# Create connection to SQL Server 2008 in Jaspersoft iReport Designer 4.0.2?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, ireport

I cannot create connection to SQL Server 2008 with Jaspersoft iReport designer 4.0.2..

When I test my connection I got an error

> SQL problems: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed.
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>   jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=qlks

`qlks` is my database name.

I use JDBC Driver :MS SQLServer (2005) (`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`)
JDBC URL : jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=qlks

I entered my username and password.

please help me!

I need it for my Java project at school!

Thanks!